# Prove if : $y\leq n , x \leq m \longleftrightarrow (x,y)R(m,n)$ and $A=N\times N$ and the same $A=Q\times Q$ Partially ordered set

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to check if the following are Partially ordered set

1. $y\leq n , x \leq m \longleftrightarrow (x,y)R(m,n)$ and $A=N\times
       N$
2. $y\leq n , x \leq m \longleftrightarrow (x,y)R(m,n)$ and $A=Q\times
           Q$

so the conditions are:

1. if for all $a \in A$(the functions set) implies $(a,a)\in R
       \rightarrow$ Reflexivity
2. for all $(a,b) \in R , (b,a) \in R \rightarrow a=b $ i.e. Anti - Symmetry
3. if for all $(a,b) \in R $ and $(b,c) \in R \rightarrow (a,c)\in R $ Transitivity

so for (1.) its reflexivity,anti-symmetry,transitiviy
for (2.) I need some advice how to prove it.
In addition if its partially ordered set I want to find the minimal and maximal terms.
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation on $A=\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ is $(x,y)\le_A(m,n)$ if and only if $x\le m$ and $y\le n$.

Notice that for any $(x,y)\in A$, we have $(x,y)\le_A (x,y)$, so $\le_A$ is reflexive.  Now if we have both $(x,y)\le_A(m,n)$ and $(m,n)\le_A(x,y)$, notice this will imply that $x=m$ and $y=n$, so that $\le_A$ is anti-symmetric.  Now, see if you can show why the transitivity of $\le_A$ follows from the transitivity of the usual order $\le$ on $\mathbb{N}$.

Notice that nothing in this proof used anything specific to the natural numbers, so it applies in the case $A=\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ as well.

For minimal and maximal terms of $A$, we will need minimal and maximal terms of $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$.  Can you see why?  Do any such exist?

Comment: there is few minimal and maximal right? this is the reason?

Comment: @Ofir: Does $\Bbb N$ have a minimal element? If so, what is it? Does $\Bbb Q$ have a minimal element? If so, what is? What about the same questions for maximal elements?